sample or density transform based on zoom domain
I have a large timeseries dataset that when zoomed-out brings the interactive plot to a crawl. Has anyone experimented with dynamically reducing the dataset size based on the zoom level? Such as the sampling transform where the sample number applies to the visible data not the entire dataset, but then disabled beyond a certain domain size. Is such a thing possible?
Here is a mock-up:

This is how I generated the data:
dt2 = datetime.datetime.now()
ydt = datetime.timedelta(days=365)
dt1 = dt2 - ydt
dt1 = dt1.timestamp()
dt2 = dt2.timestamp()
times = [random.uniform(dt1, dt2) for i in range(10**5)]
times.sort()
values = []
for t in times:
    d = {}
    t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
    t = t.isoformat(" ", timespec="seconds")
    v = random.uniform(0, 1000)
    c = random.randint(0,1)
    d["time"] = t
    d["data"] = v
    d["category"] = c
    values.append(d)

with open("./test.json", "wt") as f:
    json.dump(values[:10**4], f)

And here is what I've been able to achieve in the Vega Editor (I had to trim the data to fit the link).

Is this solved?

I'll give this answer a shot after I finish working out a solution to my previous question.

Signals are not officially supported in VL but you can hack them in. Here, the span of the domain is calculated and depending on the value, a sample is taken. You can obviously expand the ternary statement with more conditions or come up with an expression for your logic.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:12:40", "data": 265.1037232391961, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:15:26", "data": 989.2391954577464, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:15:29", "data": 426.3748533977788, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:18:11", "data": 563.7725296786067, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:21:25", "data": 322.4493083566362, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:24:54", "data": 822.6771646740021, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 15:28:10",
        "data": 294.37404484299054,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:28:22", "data": 838.7462086185608, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:35:58", "data": 961.3893188770259, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 15:36:07",
        "data": 241.45631836625802,
        "category": 0
      },
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 15:49:33",
        "data": 191.96326506124362,
        "category": 0
      },
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 15:51:15",
        "data": 450.50733664623965,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:56:35", "data": 390.5921971631632, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 15:57:52", "data": 829.8364876130439, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:01:06", "data": 996.0349700996576, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:02:36", "data": 78.24722444300802, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:14:05", "data": 942.3350040849994, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:14:56", "data": 860.58714895142, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:15:08", "data": 515.199102407516, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 16:23:20",
        "data": 166.05721829849873,
        "category": 1
      },
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 16:30:05",
        "data": 439.73137493646266,
        "category": 0
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:32:31", "data": 869.245076742056, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 16:35:48",
        "data": 480.50968063008304,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:37:50", "data": 476.877035209344, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:39:36", "data": 733.3017448826324, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:44:17", "data": 636.686519092496, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:45:08", "data": 694.5261775005811, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:51:36", "data": 695.7401884245502, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 16:55:29", "data": 570.0935946720598, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 16:57:05",
        "data": 277.22052647262717,
        "category": 0
      },
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 16:58:27",
        "data": 480.36926264607274,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:02:34", "data": 893.3698570026319, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 17:05:32",
        "data": 236.71895124154685,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:08:46", "data": 573.0841835923452, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:14:37", "data": 191.7254918774728, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:16:43", "data": 94.93763899240804, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:24:40", "data": 936.4038465823089, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 17:31:09",
        "data": 390.84825100994567,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:35:35", "data": 14.48187309843274, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 17:35:47",
        "data": 443.05398617944593,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:40:44", "data": 30.0828399028229, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:48:33", "data": 768.0549896500464, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 17:53:29", "data": 71.57068127924227, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:04:56", "data": 594.7138236213322, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:06:44", "data": 29.21370270526036, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:28:22", "data": 852.7093808483378, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:30:01", "data": 576.9728506525139, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:31:41", "data": 968.1882202042807, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:31:51", "data": 185.6873327854428, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:33:31", "data": 258.211113709635, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:36:36", "data": 641.264570256715, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:39:52", "data": 717.6143367808544, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:39:52", "data": 191.4611806426172, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:41:38", "data": 136.9116350629923, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:57:48", "data": 62.11343548023751, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 18:58:26", "data": 529.5089127094398, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 19:07:54",
        "data": 153.13269404700824,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:09:17", "data": 705.4049459845114, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 19:11:07",
        "data": 300.90132125121005,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:20:25", "data": 946.4725291504993, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 19:23:48",
        "data": 319.04133613813724,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:24:25", "data": 464.2923297748929, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:28:02", "data": 836.436678063193, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:28:08", "data": 5.992853044164859, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:40:01", "data": 873.6847072580948, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:43:41", "data": 431.0286183407737, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 19:51:22",
        "data": 396.43260404732825,
        "category": 0
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:54:08", "data": 575.9715221353141, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 19:55:53",
        "data": 44.016217670442614,
        "category": 0
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 19:58:14", "data": 988.9639046666363, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:05:53", "data": 742.2798696276691, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:07:13", "data": 982.7119961613008, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:15:20", "data": 976.3381077100345, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:20:15", "data": 498.5276910780252, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:22:29", "data": 301.4863894174468, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 20:31:03",
        "data": 232.56452406666895,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:33:52", "data": 694.171014904713, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 20:35:45",
        "data": 102.79567934930212,
        "category": 1
      },
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 20:47:32",
        "data": 431.64822699883376,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:55:19", "data": 683.217576875891, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 20:55:36", "data": 879.5945045918183, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:04:28", "data": 164.6834561802648, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 21:06:04",
        "data": 22.588620229922583,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:07:10", "data": 757.0796861192514, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:23:43", "data": 848.456892794343, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 21:34:38",
        "data": 447.89147371830785,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:45:30", "data": 862.3116375036777, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:47:00", "data": 967.0312319533795, "category": 0},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:47:56", "data": 966.4938018703745, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:49:45", "data": 890.2567189914545, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 21:55:40",
        "data": 362.80312104639677,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 21:58:55", "data": 834.7469369912607, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 22:01:02", "data": 584.1447613550432, "category": 1},
      {"time": "2023-08-31 22:01:06", "data": 82.66592460479994, "category": 1},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 22:02:00",
        "data": 332.67959271479384,
        "category": 0
      },
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 22:02:32",
        "data": 316.51081491367347,
        "category": 0
      },
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 22:08:31",
        "data": 336.10098602094985,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 22:18:52", "data": 873.7313013506864, "category": 0},
      {
        "time": "2023-08-31 22:19:24",
        "data": 312.42947148514776,
        "category": 1
      },
      {"time": "2023-08-31 22:28:48", "data": 582.8096654568776, "category": 1}
    ]
  },
  "params": [{"name": "test", "expr": "span(grid_time)/100000"}],
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.data > 0"},
    {"sample": {"signal": "test<130?100:10"}}
  ],
  "title": "Too Much Data",
  "config": {"font": "monospace"},
  "width": "container",
  "layer": [
    {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "grid",
          "bind": "scales",
          "select": {
            "type": "interval",
            "encodings": ["x"],
            "on": "[mousedown[!event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
            "translate": "[mousedown[!event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "brush",
          "select": {
            "type": "interval",
            "encodings": ["x"],
            "on": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
            "translate": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!"
          }
        }
      ],
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "time", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "data", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"param": "brush"}},
        {"aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "count"}]}
      ],
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ]
}


Hmm I was considering adding a grid_time JS signal handler and manually decimating the data via changesets, but this is so much simpler, thanks! I no longer have to worry if it's safe to change the data in the handler, and safe to call runAsync, or how to insert while preserving order. Only time will tell if the sample transform is sufficient in preserving the shape of my data, or I need a more complicated curve-decimation algorithm in JS.

I'd like to visualize the test param to aid in writing an expression for my logic - is this possible?

Mark this as solved and ask a new question with sample data and the exact new requirement as I'm not 100% clear what you mean

No need for another question, I've figured it out. test can be visualized in on the plot and in the console as ... text: {expr: "warn(test)"} ..., as opposed to data entries which are available under datum, or data('name') for specific sources.

I've got a heuristic which averages to about X points displayed: total_count_orig / (grid_count_orig / X). The orig data source is presorted so I'm using an efficient binary search. It's nifty to see the points appear and disappear as I zoom, but unfortunately the performance is untenable the further zoomed in I get. With X=400 and never peaking above 425 (my data is pretty regular), it quickly slows to a crawl, even when I'm so far zoomed in there are only 10-20 data points visible.

Once I zoom out the performance is restored. I suspect sample is resampling from scratch whenever the grid/view signal changes, and it gets very slow when it has to filter out nearly all the data. Please let me know if there's a more performant approach!

VegaLite isn't meant for huge numbers of individual data points - data should typically be aggregated somehow before visualising it. You probably need to look at something like https://github.com/vega/vega-plus which can handle millions of records

Just like this question my data is pretty simple - x (time), y, and color encodings. It's already pre-filtered so I'm not using any transforms. This makes me think a project like VegaFusion will not help me, but VegaPlus may be overkill. Do you know of any Vega projects that can stream from an sqlite database?

I'm collecting data over a large time period so there are about 50,000 rows (and I want to vconcat another two plots), but I'm only using simple point-style marks. Despite 50,000 rows I'm only interested in rendering 500 or so marks at a time. The real main problem is sample. It is ridiculously slow and shuffles my data. Do you think its worth trying to replace it with filter. I would create X bins and assign every row a bin. When the view/grid signal triggers I'd calculate the current binned zoom level (out of X) and filter out all rows >= x.

50k is still quite large but yes, I would go down the filter route. The problem is when fully zoomed out, you will also need to bin too as 50k points is probably too many to display at once. Mark this question as solved and ask a new one with your attempt if you're still struggling

Filter has the same problem - the more you zoom in the slower VegaLite becomes, even if you are only panning, and only panning 5-10 marks. And like sample it reorders my data, though at least each individual bin remains sorted when reintroduced, which should work well with Chrome's timsort.

Interesting.... If you first filter on {param: grid} the plot becomes much more responsive when zoomed. Apparently the entire dataset is filtered, even entries out-of-sight, but filtering on a selection predicate is much better optimized, so subsequent filters need only filter the visible data.

Nevermind... it simply changed my sample heuristic to be less aggressive (show more points). Its interesting how showing more points can be significantly faster than an aggressive sampling.

I've taken a look at the sample source and I believe I can improve its performance for my use, though if sufficiently I'm not sure. Taking a look at VegaFusion or VegaPlus, these are engines that offload difficult computations onto a separate database processor. I don't have those so I'm not sure they meet my needs. Sure, streaming the data would behave like the sampler I need but I'm not sure its worth the effort. For my specific use, do you think I should focus on a custom sampler or a 3rd-party vega project?

Anyway, if you know how to create a custom vega.transform in vega-lite, I'd appreciate it.

Can you ask a new question with a full working spec and all 50k datapoints loaded. You might be able to filter and sample using existing transforms but it is impossible to test without data and a spec. VL is more limited and you might have more options with Vega too.

Create a gist for your data so you can share a link without it being too big
